# ordinal numbers with uncountable nouns

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns, ordinals

I know countables can be used with ordinal numbers. We can say "the second book," etc. But what about uncountables like "information"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you please give a full sentence example (or even better more than one) of the form you are unsure about. It is not clear to me how you want to use "information" in connection with an ordinal number. (And "the second book" does not contain any plural form.)

Comment: @DavidSiegel Question edited.

Comment: @ The scenario is easy to imagine. There might be times when I want to say "the second information," meaning the second piece of information.

Comment: Then you would say "the second piece of information."

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about singular and plural used with ordinal numbers.

If you had three piles of books and you were telling people to take the second book from each pile, you might say **remove the second books**, but there's nothing special about this usage. When referring to a single pile, you would say **remove the second book**.

*Information* by itself as a noun usually refers to something abstract and non-tangible, so you can't make it plural. To make it specific and tangible, you must qualify it. When you qualify it, the qualifier becomes the noun and information becomes an adjective. If there is more than one, you make the noun (qualifier) plural.

For example, if you told someone:

**refer to the information provided**

*information* refers to something abstract, so you can't make it plural. It could be an unknown quantity of data or it might not even be the same for everyone, depending on what was provided to different people.

To make it specific and tangible, you need to qualify it, for example:

**refer to the information *sheet* provided**.

If there is more than one sheet, you would say,:

**refer to the information *sheets* provided**.

If you want the person to look at the second sheet, you would say

**refer to the second information *sheet* provided**

Whether you use ordinal numbers has no bearing on the result.